# Calculation of density altitude

Tags: navigation, e6b

When using an e6b flight computer which temperature will I use with the pressure altitude to get the density altitude

Comment: What are the choices?

Comment: Current outside air temperature.

Comment: You might do a Google search for an answer to your question and you'll likely find additional helpful information/explanations on using the e6b as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the outside air temperature at the location you are calculating density altitude for.